# PDO Cant connect to DB

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Ive recently moved to a cloud server nd my sites no longer connect to the DB, all config settings are the same only I get this error...

```
ERROR: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'access@tmysute.co.uk'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Ive double checked the passwords and username and all is correct, has anybody had this problem before?

Comment: try connect your MySql server across MySql client.

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind your mysql server to 0.0.0.0 instead 127.0.0.1 or just comment bind-address part. This is [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/139323/mysql-bind-to-more-than-one-ip-address) on how to :)

Answer (score 0):

Your database has to be configurated to allow connections from non local IPs.
It's common pracise on shared hosts, You have to migrate Your DB or talk with admin.